# Find all files in a folder and group by part of the filename

Tags: php, foreach, scandir

I have a folder containing images like so:

- colorwaves-1.png
- colorwaves-2.png
- snow-1.png
- snow-2.png

I need to populate a drop-down list that contains only:

- colorwaves
- snow

this is my code:

```
<?php
$files = scandir('../resources/banner/');
foreach ($files as $file)
  if ($file != "." && $file != ".."){
  $x = array_shift(explode('-', $file));  //remove everything after "-"
  echo "<option value='".$x."'>".$x."</option>";
}
?>
```

This will give me of course 4 results with two duplicates.
I cant find a way to filter the results before I start the loop.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant find a way to filter the results before I start the loop.

`scandir`  returns an array with all the file and directory names within the given directory.

You want to filter this array (remove entries) that are duplicates of a changed name.

You so far know how to change a name:

```
$name = strtok($file, '-');
```

You also have an additional filter-condition that you don't want the dot-entries with the single and the double dots.

```
($file != "." && $file != "..")
```

And in the end you need to filter the duplicates.

So let's bring this all together. First of all you have to obtain the directory listing:

```
$path = '../resources/banner/';

$files = scandir($path);
```

To filter the array, you can make use of [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$files = array_filter($files, function($file) {
    return ($file != "." && $file != "..");
});
```

With this filter applied, the dot entries have been removed already. Next is to normalize the names. This can be done with [mapping a callback function](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$files = array_map(function($file) {
    return strtok($file, '-');
}, $files);
```

With this mapping applied, the names of all files have been created.

Now you need to remove duplicate entries. This can be done with [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique):

```
$files = array_unique($files);
```

After the array has been processed the way you wish, you only need to output it:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    printf("<option value='%1\$s'>%1\$s</option>", htmlspecialchars($file));
}
```

Bringing this all together ([Demo](https://eval.in/332755)):

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30092161/367456
 */

$path = '.';

$files = scandir($path);

$files = array_filter($files, function($file) {
    return ($file != "." && $file != "..");
});

$files = array_map(function($file) {
    return strtok($file, '-');
}, $files);

$files = array_unique($files);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    printf("<option value='%1\$s'>%1\$s</option>\n", htmlspecialchars($file));
}
```

I hope this is helpful and demonstrates some programming tips:

- separate your program logic into three main parts: input, processing and output.
- when processing data, divide it into multiple small steps so that each step does on thing and does it right. you can then build your program step by step and always try it in the meantime if it still works.
- PHP has many array functions. If you use arrays, use them. The PHP manual discusses each of them, I've shown three basic ones: array_filter, array_map and array_unique.
- callback functions allow you to extend PHP core functionality (or: other persons code) with your own code. there is no need to write all from scratch. look for functionality to re-use.
- when you output HTML, you have to encode your data properly (here: as HTML). As you can't control the names in the directory listing, HTML could be otherwise injected. *Always* encode your data properly on output.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you have put into this. This makes sense to me and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of what you've found, and only do the output portion AFTER you've processed everything:

```
$data = array();
foreach(...) {
    $text = function_to_extract_relevant_filename_portion();
    $data[$text] = true;
}
$file_name_parts = array_keys($data);
... output filename parts here ...
```

You could combine both loops, and simply NOT output anything if you've already previously output a particular name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
$files = array_values(array_filter(array_unique(array_map(function($a){ if(!in_array($a, array('.','..'))){ $a = explode('-', $a); return "<option value='".$a[0]."'>".$a[0]."</option>"; }}, $files))));
```

The `array_map()` anonymous callback returns the option if it's not `'.'` or `'..'`. The `array_unique()` removes duplicates. The `array_filter()` removes empties. The `array_values`, which is optional, resets the array keys.

**EDIT:**
Here's a one-liner with the `scandir` included and the select element included:

```
return '<select>'.implode(' ', array_values(array_filter(array_unique(array_map(function($a){ if(!in_array($a, array('.','..'))){ $a = explode('-', $a); return "<option value='".$a[0]."'>".$a[0]."</option>"; }}, scandir('../resources/banner/')))))).'</select>';
```